# Unable to catch SAXParseException

Tags: java, rdf, jena

Hi I am using jena to read som rdf file:

```
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(adress);
    model.read(in, adress);
```

problem in second row which throw sometimes SAXParseException:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. 
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. 
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFDefaultErrorHandler.fatalError(RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:45)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.fatalError(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:35)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:225)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.fatalError(XMLHandler.java:255)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanQName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:142)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:158)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:145)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:215)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:197)
```

so I want to do some try catch block. The problem is when I do this, compiler return:

> exception org.xml.sax.SAXParseException is never thrown in body of
>   corresponding try statement

So how I can chatch this exception ? I know that I can catch just Exception but then I cannot be sure where the problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAXParserException is a "checked-exception" meaning that the method signature is forced to declare it, if it throws. Obviously, the method you call does not declare it, so you cannot catch it.

It looks like Jena is actually wrapping that exception in an "unchecked-exception" (ie, an exception that extends RuntimeException). This exception is actually `JenaException`. So you could add a try/catch for a `JenaException` and then use `getCause()` to find the original error encoutered by Jena.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch JenaException instead of the SAXParseException. And then try to get the cause that might be the SAXParseException.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to handle problems with your RDF XML input, there is a more direct way using the [error handler interface](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/io/sax.html#error-handler) to the Jena reader.